# How to get the length of the original array according to the compressed byte array of GZIP?

Tags: java, io, gzip

Before decompressing the array compressed by GZIP, I would like to know the length of the original array so as to apply for a suitable buffer array.Like "1024" in the following code.Thanks!

```java
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
        try (ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(localByteBuf);
             GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(bin)) {
            int len;
            while ((len = gis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ByteArrayOutputStream` will take care of growing the internal `byte[]` array. As per the class javadoc:

> This class implements an output stream in which the data is
>   written into a byte array. The buffer automatically grows as data
>   is written to it.

You most likely want to copy the stream using [`InputStream.transferTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo-java.io.OutputStream-) to make the code more readable:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); // default 32 size
GZIPInputStream in = new GZIPInputStream(
        new ByteArrayInputStream(localByteBuf)));
in.transferTo(out);
```